# Doesn't pull image metadata from Docker Hub private registries

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I have deployed argocd and argocd-image-updater in my cluster. But, when argocd tries to connect to Docker Hub to get manifest I keep getting this error in the logs.

```
time="2024-01-01T08:37:18Z" level=error msg="Could not get tags from registry: errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n" alias=cloud-service application=appsmith image_name=gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd image_tag=release registry=
time="2024-01-01T08:37:18Z" level=info msg="Committing 1 parameter update(s) for application appsmith" application=appsmith
time="2024-01-01T08:37:18Z" level=info msg="Successfully updated the live application spec" application=appsmith
time="2024-01-01T08:37:18Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=1 images_considered=2 images_skipped=0 images_updated=1 errors=1"
time="2024-01-01T08:39:18Z" level=info msg="Starting image update cycle, considering 1 annotated application(s) for update"
time="2024-01-01T08:39:20Z" level=info msg="Setting new image to appsmith/appsmith-ee@sha256:87c6e786060655a70344c8dfffac2145a13b4029540c6b268c82730403366139" alias=appsmith application=appsmith image_name=appsmith/appsmith-ee image_tag=dummy registry=
time="2024-01-01T08:39:20Z" level=info msg="Successfully updated image 'appsmith/appsmith-ee@dummy' to 'appsmith/appsmith-ee@sha256:87c6e786060655a70344c8dfffac2145a13b4029540c6b268c82730403366139', but pending spec update (dry run=false)" alias=appsmith application=appsmith image_name=appsmith/appsmith-ee image_tag=dummy registry=
time="2024-01-01T08:39:22Z" level=error msg="Could not get tags from registry: errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n" alias=cloud-service application=appsmith image_name=gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd image_tag=release registry=
time="2024-01-01T08:39:22Z" level=info msg="Committing 1 parameter update(s) for application appsmith" application=appsmith
time="2024-01-01T08:39:22Z" level=info msg="Successfully updated the live application spec" application=appsmith
time="2024-01-01T08:39:22Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=1 images_considered=2 images_skipped=0 images_updated=1 errors=1"
```

In the pod when i exec and run

```
argocd-image-updater test gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd:release --update-strategy latest
```

I see this error

```
/ $ argocd-image-updater test gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd:release --update-strategy latest
DEBU[0000] Creating in-cluster Kubernetes client
INFO[0000] retrieving information about image            image_alias= image_digest= image_name=gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd image_tag=release registry_url=
INFO[0000] Fetching available tags and metadata from registry  application=test image_alias= image_digest= image_name=gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd image_tag=release registry_url=
FATA[0001] could not get tags: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required  application=test image_alias= image_digest= image_name=gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd image_tag=release registry_url=
```

My registries configmap look as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  registries.conf: |
    registries:
    - name: Docker Hub
      api_url: none
      credentials: pullsecret:argocd/appsmith
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/name":"argocd-image-updater-config","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"argocd-image-updater"},"name":"argocd-image-updater-config","namespace":"argocd"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-01-01T07:26:36Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-image-updater-config
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd-image-updater
  name: argocd-image-updater-config
  namespace: argocd
  resourceVersion: "225812617"
  uid: a27b5695-06eb-424e-bbe7-60db4b32d2f6
```

Same creds work when i do a docker login

```
(base) ➜  Pictures docker login --username xxxxx --password xxxxxxx
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.

Login Succeeded
(base) ➜  Pictures docker pull index.docker.io/gouthamappsmith/test-argocd:release
release: Pulling from gouthamappsmith/test-argocd
c926b61bad3b: Downloading [=========================>                         ]   1.71MB/3.402MB
e5820a814e8c: Downloading [=====>                                             ]  1.453MB/13.14MB
7b4bda58fd3f: Downloading [=>                                                 ]  947.1kB/46.85MB
```

I created the secret as follows

```
kubectl create -n argocd secret docker-registry appsmith --docker-username=xxxx --docker-password=xxx
```

and it is working in the same cluster as imagePullSecrets.
Also, occasionally I see Too many pull Requests despite providing my credentials and authenticating myself

Am I missing anything?

Comment: why `api_url` is empty `none`  ? shouldn't be something like `https://registry-1.docker.io` ??

Comment: my images are hosted on hub.docker.com and if i give registry-1.docker.io . I see that it is searching in that url and not the actual one. So, gave it as none.

Comment: [The docs](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration/registries/#configuration-format) says that `api_url` should be defined  and its value  is `https://registry-1.docker.io`  and then try this command `argocd-image-updater test gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd:release --update-strategy latest --kubeconfig  ~/.kube/config  --registries-conf ./argocd-image-updater.conf` So you have to add another record for `https://registry-1.docker.io` in `~/.docker/config.json` before it  creates the pull secret.

Comment: Even without that also. I did this by giving env creds and it worked ```argocd-image-updater test gouthamappsmith/tests-argocd:release --update-strategy latest --credentials env:DOCKER_HUB_CREDS --loglevel debug```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked.

Create a secret using dockerhub PAT using the following [link](https://docs.docker.com/security/for-developers/access-tokens/#create-an-access-token)

```
cat docker-secret.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dockerhub
  namespace: argocd
type: Opaque
stringData:
  token: gouthamappsmith:xxxxxxxxxx
```

argocd-image-updater.yaml as the following

```
---
image:
  tag: "latest"

metrics:
  enabled: true

config:
  registries:
    - name: Docker Hub
      credentials: secret:argocd/dockerhub#token
      api_url: https://registry-1.docker.io
      ping: yes
      default: true
```

Installed argcd-image-updater using the following

```
helm upgrade -i updater -n argocd argo/argocd-image-updater -f argocd-image-updater.yaml
```